# Updating model extension properties in Teiid fails

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-6, teiid

I'm having issues updating Teiid 8.6 model extension properties via JDBC. I can query the metadata, but I get an error while trying to issue an UPDATE command.

```
   update "SYS"."Properties" set "Value" = 'VAL1' where "Name" = '{http://example.com/extmodel}prop1' and "UID" = 'mmuuid:e61b4b62-e874-4715-95a8-a5b04e916f5c' and "OID" is null
```

I get this:

```
org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: 
TEIID30492 Remote org.teiid.api.exception.query.QueryValidatorException: 
TEIID30492 Metadata does not allow updates on the group: SYS.Properties
```

Is there a way to update these properties?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says the system metadata is not updatable at runtime. How you can update depends upon which kind of VDB you used. If you are using Dynamic VDB, then you can update the DDL, in OPTIONS properties for Table, Procedure etc.

If you are using the Designer, then you can select the table. stored procedure and update in the properties window.

Teiid 9.x roapmap has feature to update runtime metadata, once that feature is implemented then you can accomplish as you mention above.